# How to move UIImageView in order to always keep image's head forward?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

Assume I have an `UIImageView` in `ViewController's` view, and this `UIImageView` contains an image.
As an example, let it be a car image with the car's head directing towards north by default.

I want to do some rotation and movement on the UIImageView (containing the car image).

I use `CGAffineTransformRotate` function to rotate it

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_ImageView.transform, angle);
```

I assign values to tx and ty of newTransform.

Since the values of tx and ty are in `UIImageView's` coordinate system, this coordinate system of the `UIImageView` won't be rotated.

My question is: Is there any easy way to get the value of tx and ty such that `UIImageView` moves straightforward with the direction of image's head.

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to move the imageview

```
-(void)move:(id)sender {

    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self];

     if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
         _firstX = [self center].x;
         _firstY = [self center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(_firstX+translatedPoint.x, _firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    [self setCenter:translatedPoint];


    [self showOverlayWithFrame:self.frame];

}
```